# Java delete or modify one record in File

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

```
// Create file 
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(fileName, true); 
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 
    out.write(c.toString()); 
    //Close the output stream 
    out.close(); 

    // Code I used to read record I am using | as a seperator name and id 
    String fileName = folderPath + "listCatalogue.txt"; 
    String line = ""; 
    Scanner scanner; 
    String name, id; 
    scanner = new Scanner(fileName); 
    System.out.println(scanner.hasNextLine()); 
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
        line = scanner.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println(line); 
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|"); 
        name = st.nextToken(); 
        id = st.nextToken(); 
        catalogues.add(new Catalogue(name, id)); 
    }
```

Above is the code to create file and read file, How can I do delete certain record, in File, what I have found from google  is delete the file but not delete certain record example I provide name, if match delete this record. As well as modify that record? Is it possible to do modify record using File?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting certain record in file is impossible for several reasons.

First, record is your application level term. File system knows only sequence of bytes. Second streams you are using to access file are abstractions that do not support deletion as well.

So, what's the  solution.

1. You can read file record-by record and write other file record-by-record unless you see record you want to delete. Avoid writing this record to other file. This gives you effect of deletion.  But this method is not effective for big files.
2. File streams support `mark()` and `skip()` methods. If you data structure allows retrieving the position of record you want to delete you can arrive to this position immediately by calling `skip()`. The problem is to delete. to solve it you should either create data structure that allows marking record as deleted. In this case you do not really delete record but just mark it as deleted. Other solution is to write special (e.g. null) values over the record but your reader have to be able to skip such null values.
   This solution has disadvantage: if you remove many records the file is will not be smaller.

Variant: you can use RandomAccessFile API. You can also use FileChannel.